# Sort Google Keep "Titles" in alphabetical order

Tags: google-keep

Google Keep "Labels" are sorted automatically in alphabetical order.
How do I sort "Titles"in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there doesn't seem to be any built-in functionality for sorting, nor do any third-party extensions exist to add notes sorting.

You can make a feature request by sending Google feedback from the keep.google.com web app. Click on the Settings icons, then on Send Feedback, and in the new pop-up describe the notes sorting functionality you'd like to see being implemented.